# Quicksight - Calculated Field (in Analysis) To Show Percent That Field = "TRUE"

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I feel like there must be a very easy way to do this, but I'm missing it.

In my data set, I have a 'success' column that's a boolean value of 'TRUE' or 'FALSE'. I want to create a calculated field *within a dashboard* that is basically 'successRate' that for a given facet of data aggregated, will show the success rate (% of true for all values).

I feel like I could solve this by creating another calculated field where I convert to 0 or 1 based on column 'success', then create another calculated field to average that. However - I really feel like there is a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

I did like this:

```
sum(ifelse(success='True',1,0))/count(ifelse(success='True',1,0))
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**